# I want to count the unique combination of columns from Postgresql db using sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a db table having columns x and y, I want to count the unique combination of both the column x and y and get the count value using sequelize query.
[image]

i want the query result something like this

```
[
  { x: 821, y: 289, value: 1 },
  { x: 819, y: 290, value: 1 },
  { x: 820, y: 290, value: 1 },
  { x: 821, y: 291, value: 1 },
  { x: 823, y: 293, value: 2 },
  { x: 822, y: 291, value: 5 },
  { x: 820, y: 291, value: 1 },
  { x: 821, y: 290, value: 1 },
  { x: 823, y: 291, value: 2 },
..............................]
```

I tried this but didn't got the required result

```
tableData.findAll({
      attributes:[ ["x", "y"],
      [db.fn('COUNT', (db.fn('DISTINCT', db.col("x"), db.col("y")))), "value"]
    ],
      where: {
        store_id: storeId,
        zone_id: zoneId,
        timestamp: {
          [Op.between]: [starDate, endDate],
        },
      },
      group: [["x","y"],"timestamp"],
      order: [
        ['timestamp', 'DESC'],
    ],
      limit: 2000
    }).then((data) => {
```

The above query giving me data like, which is wrong format

```
[
  { y: '819', value: '1' }, { y: '820', value: '1' }, { y: '821', value: '1' },
  { y: '820', value: '1' }, { y: '821', value: '2' }, { y: '822', value: '1' },
  { y: '823', value: '1' }, { y: '823', value: '2' }, { y: '822', value: '2' },
  { y: '823', value: '1' }, { y: '824', value: '1' }, { y: '819', value: '1' },
  { y: '821', value: '1' }, { y: '823', value: '2' }, { y: '817', value: '2' },
  { y: '819', value: '1' }, { y: '820', value: '1' }, { y: '821', value: '1' }...]
```

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do little change here and there throughout the query and finally, I got the data in the format I wanted.
Posting my answer, Hoping it could be useful for others.

Please correct me if I am wrong or you have a better approach.

```
tableData.findAll({
      attributes:["x", "y",
      [db.fn('COUNT', db.col("*")), "value"]
    ],
      where: {
        store_id: storeId,
        zone_id: zoneId,
        timestamp: {
          [Op.between]: [starDate, endDate],
        },
      },
      group: ["x","y"],
      limit: 2000
    }).then((data) => {})
```